# Is it possible to make a backup node for Envoy as a gateway

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I'm a backend engineer and for now the backend servers of my company are all deployed on physical machines.

Today my leader told me that we would use Kubernetes to re-deploy the whole backend servers and we should consider making the servers high-available. Furthermore, we will use Envoy as our gateway of the backend.

Now I've two questions:

1. I just read the official doc of Envoy but it doesn't seem to provide us the doc about how to deploy an Envoy with K8S. Does it mean that deploying the Envoy with K8S as the gateway is not good?
2. Is it possible to make two or three pods of Envoy as the backup of the gateway? Since we are considering the high-availability, I'm thinking I should make some backup nodes for the gateway, if one fails, the other one should be awaken.

The architecture:

```
APP -> Gateway(Envoy) -> micro-servers
```

The two questions are all about the `Gateway` part.

Comment: it is possible,explained here https://www.getambassador.io/resources/envoy-as-api-gateway/.

Comment: Both on-prem and with cloud providers.